# Are songs streamed from iTunes Match stored somewhere on the Mac hard drive?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I've installed iTunes Match and started to stream some songs. I was just wondering, where are they stored during streaming?I have a MacBook Pro, with Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

The songs are stored in the iTunes library, just like all other songs in iTunes. To find the storage location of a specific song, right-click it in iTunes and select "Show/Reveal in Finder" (or the equivalent in your language).

Comment: i'm playing songs from icloud. If i right click on it i have the options to download the song, i was wondering if they are stored in some cache wheni just play them

Comment: Ah, you are streaming them then? They are cached (otherwise you wouldn't be able to jump back and forth) but I don't know where (if at all) they are on disk.